# SubMenù disappearing after parent menù Item looses focus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, hover

I have an html dropdown menu.

Problems are 
1. When hovering over a parent menu item, the child menu is displayed ok. When hovering over the child menù however this disappear, making it useless.
2. Children submenù item background color is not right even though I have set it to rgba(17, 91, 164, .6) and added the !important directive;

HTML

```
                  <div class="mainMenu" id="mainMenu">
                <ul>
                  <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem1"> <a href="./squadra.html">Squadra</a> </li>
                  <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem2"> <a href="./biglietti.html">Biglietti</a> </li>
                  <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem3"> <a href="sottoscrizioneAbbonamento1.html">Abbonamenti</a> </li>
                  <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem4"> <a href="ritiro.html">Ritiro</a> </li>
                  <li class="menuItem" id="menuItem5"> <a href="fidelityCard.html">Fidelity Card</a> </li>
                  <li class="menuItem active" id="menuItem7"> <span> <a href="account.html">Account</a> </span>

                    <ul class="mainSubMenu">
                        <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="profilo.html">Profilo</a></li>
                        <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="datiFatturazione.html">Dati Fatturazione</a></li>
                        <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="storicoTifoso.html">Storico Tifoso</a></li>
                        <li class="subMenuItem"><a class="pureCssMenui" href="esci.html">Esci</a></li>
                    </ul>


                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
```

CSS

```
#mainMenu
{
font-size: 0.85em;
padding:10px 0 0px 0;

border:white 2px;
background: rgba(17, 91, 164, .6);
height:50px;

/*overflow:hidden;*/
}

#mainMenu ul
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    list-style-type: none;
}



#mainMenu ul li
{

    height:20px;
    float:left;

    text-align:center;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:1.7em;
    margin-left:.5em;
    margin-right:.5em;
    max-width:180px;

    padding:15px !important;


}

#mainMenu ul li:hover, #mainMenu ul li.active
{
background: rgba(17, 91, 164, 1);
border-top: rgba(17, 91, 164, 1) 15px;
}

#mainMenu ul li a, #mainMenu ul li span a
{
    color:brown;
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#FFF;

    font-weight:bold;


}

.accountMenuItem
{
    /*margin-left:88px !important;*/

}

.mainSubMenu
{
display:none;

z-index:100!important;
background: rgba(17, 91, 164, 1) !important;
color:black !important;
font-size:1em!important;
}


/*.mainMenu:hover   .mainSubMenu {display:block }*/

.mainMenu ul li:hover > ul{display:block;}
.mainMenu ul li ul li:hover  {display:block;}

#mainMenu ul li ul
{
position: relative;
left:-2px; top:98%;
background: rgba(17, 91, 164, 1) !important;
color:white;
}

#mainMenu ul ul ul
{position: relative; left:98%; top:-2px;}

#mainMenu ul ul
{
    width:119.7px;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Can somebody please help me? For your convenience I have uploaded and example page: http://prova.webuda.com/account.html.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Rather than uploading an example page (which may not be available to users down the road, should you choose to remove it), could you create a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your positioning on the lists. From the example you provided, I was able to make the following modifications via Chrome's DevTools and the menu worked. I believe your current code is positioning the submenu off screen. The parent LI needs to be relative to the rest of the page, and the submenu needs to be absolutely positioned inside the parent LI.

```
#mainMenu ul li {
    position: relative;
}

#mainMenu ul li ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```